# Is a long IN clause a code smell?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, performance

Simple question. Wondering if a long IN clause is a code smell? I don't really know how to justify it. I can't put my finger on why it smells other than that I think it does.

```
select
  name,
  code,
  capital,
  population,
  flower,
  bird
from us_states
where
  code in
    ('NJ', 'NY', 'PA', 'CA', 'AL', 'AK', 'AZ',
    'IL', 'IN', 'KY', 'KS', 'DC', 'MD', 'MA')
```

How does a database typically implement such a lookup? Is a temporary table made and joined to? Or is it just expanded into a series of logical ORs?

It feels like it should have been a join...

I'm not saying all IN clauses are bad. Sometimes you can't help it. But there are some cases (particularly the longer they get) where the set of elements you're matching against actually comes from somewhere. And shouldn't that be joined on instead?

Is it worth creating (via the application level) a temporary table that has all the elements you want to search against and then doing a real join against that?

```
select u.*
from us_states u

join #chosen_states t
on u.code = t.code
```

Comment: If you want to know how *your* database is performing these queries, use EXPLAIN to get output about the query execution.  http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/using-explain.html

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think it is a code smell. For one thing, databases have limits as to the number of elements allowed in an `IN` clause, and if your SQL is generated dynamically, you may eventually bump up against those limits.

When the list starts to become long-ish, I would convert to using a stored procedure with a temporary table, to avoid any chance of errors.

I doubt performance is a major concern though, `IN` clauses are very fast, as they can short-circuit, unlike `NOT IN` clauses.

Comment: +1.  Recently I picked up some maintenance work for an existing app (written by someone else,) which used the IN clause to exclude email addresses (by concatenating string.)  Problem is, the app was now being migrated to a database with over 20 million records and possibly millions to be excluded.  I could not believe it was designed that way, even for the original testing database.  I like the `in (<subquery>)` syntax though.

Comment: "I would convert to using a stored procedure with a temporary table" -- assuming the proposed stored procedure is permanent, why not also use a permanent base table?

Comment: @onedaywhen My assumption is that the data is only being used once for that query, so there is no point in storing it permanently.

Comment: @RedFilter: the way I see it, if the table must exist each time the proc is called then there's no point in ever dropping the table unless the proc itself is dropped ...or is there something I'm not seeing?

Answer (score 4):

> Is it worth creating (via the application level) a temporary table.

The problem with `IN` is that it doesn't use an index and the comparison *(worst case: x14 here)* gets repeated for every row in your source table.

Creating a temp table is a good idea, if you put an index on the join fields.
That way the query can lookup the value directly, using a BTree index that should only take 3 or 4 comparisons worst case log2(14) = 3.something
Which is much faster.

If you're smart you can even use a `hash-index` in which case the DB only needs to do 1 comparison, speeding your query up 3 fold compared to the btree index.

**Tips for using a temp table**
Make sure to use a memory table
Use a `hash index` as your primary key.
Try and do the inserts in one statement.

The semi-constant time you'll spend creating the temp-table will be dwarfed by the speedup because of the O(1) lookup time using the hash index.

Comment: This kind of tuning isn't so general, though.  Remember that you have to account for the time to build the temp table and its index.  For one off queries on a table with a small row count, it's best to just let it do the brute force compare of the IN clause.  For repeated queries w/ the same IN clause, or for very large row counts, it's better to create the temp table and index.  It's best to get familiar with the query planner to be able to weigh these things yourself.

Comment: @Ben Burns, If your temp table has 10 rows and your comparing it with a million row table, the speed up will be enough to justify the build-up even if you only use it only once. Try it out. I'm thinking if you compare against a 1,000 row table it will still be faster to do the temp table.

Comment: @Ben, good point though, always profile your solutions and try stuff out, never assume.

Comment: We're saying the same thing, Johan.  I'd guess the threshold is higher than 1k rows, but that's kind of the point - w/o profiling and an understanding of data growth, it's just a guess.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know that it's a code smell, exactly.  Sometimes you just have a long list of things `in` which your condition could exist.

As for making a temp table (or even a lookup table) with the elements and joining against (or even doing a `where [column] in (select [lookup] from [lookuptable])` is one of my preferred methods IFF* a) There are a large number of values that b) will change seldom if ever.

*: "If and Only If"

Answer (score 0):

You can also use a subquery with IN, as described [here in the manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/any-in-some-subqueries.html).

```
SELECT * FROM us_states WHERE code IN (SELECT code FROM state_codes);
```

Comment: -1 `IN (SELECT X FROM y)` is notoriously slow on MySQL and can just be replaced with an inner join: `inner join state_codes sc ON (sc.code = us_states.code)` which is much faster in MySQL.

Comment: @Johan isn't that more MySQL's fault for not being able to transform the subselect into an equivalent join?

Answer (score 0):

I too consider it a 'smell'. An `IN` clause may, to a casual observer, resemble a set, list, bag, table, etc but isn't.

According to the SQL Standards, your `IN` clause is merely syntactic sugar for

```
(
 code = 'NJ' OR code = 'NY' OR code = 'PA' OR code = 'CA' 
    OR code = 'AL' OR code = 'AK' OR code = 'AZ' 
    OR code = 'IL' OR code = 'IN' OR code = 'KY' 
    OR code = 'KS' OR code = 'DC' OR code = 'MD' 
    OR code = 'MA'
)
```

I would expect a typical parser to expand out an `IN` clause in exactly this way; I know SQL Server does because the nice, neat `IN` clauses I use to create certain `CHECK` constraints become an ugly set of `OR` clauses when I examine the constraint's definition in the INFORMATION_SCHEMA. YMMV: if you are concerned about performance, test.

There is a design rule of thumb that states, if the set of values is small and stable then use an `IN` clause, otherwise use a table. Whether 14 out of 52 is 'small' is subjective. Whether a small table is best indexed may depend on how it is joined to other tables: [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/252865/15354) may be a useful reference.

Comment: Whether or not `IN` clauses are a code smell, this is a terrible argument. You're basically saying "the standard dictates that these two syntaxes are equivalent, and one of them looks ugly, therefore we should consider the other one ugly too and not use it!" This can't possibly make sense because it's a fully general argument that any piece of code is bad; the same logic could be applied to condemn pretty much any piece of code ever written in any language. I don't see how the (obvious) equivalence of `X in (A, B, C)` and `X=A OR X=B OR X=C` has any relevance to the question.

Comment: In saying 'ugly' I was whining about SQL Server rewriting my code and agree it was irrelevant so I removed it. Do you see where I say, "merely syntactic sugar"? That's supposed to tell you that I don't think it is important whether you use `IN` or the equivalent disjunctive normal form.

Comment: Post-edit, I'm still not a fan of this answer. You bring up the equivalence or `X IN (A, B, C)` to the `X=A OR X=B OR X=C` form, but my response is to ask... *so?* You seem to be getting at something performance-related, but I don't understand how rewriting the clause as `X=A OR X=B OR X=C` gives us any insight into performance. You mention that casual observers might perceive IN clauses as being like sets, but again... *so*? What wrong inferences about performance might they therefore draw? I feel like you haven't fleshed out your thoughts enough for me to understand them.

Comment: "How does a database typically implement such a lookup? ...is it just expanded into a series of logical ORs?"

Comment: But the fact that the standard dictates that `X IN (A, B, C)` and `X=A OR X=B OR X=C` are equivalent tells us nothing at all about how the database implements the lookup. The engine is free to perform them in the same way or differently, and free to create temporary tables for either, both, or neither if it wants to. That quote from the question is clearly the OP looking for performance-related information about how the lookup is *implemented*, and the equivalence to `X=A OR X=B OR X=C` is irrelevant to that.

Comment: @MarkAmery: I disagree that the OP is looking for performance-related information. I think they are asking from a programming point of view e.g. writing `IN (values)` vs putting those values in a table and writing a `JOIN`. I suggest you write your own performance-related answer, perhaps with some timing evidence, and see if it gets any votes (perhaps from me!). If you feel strongly about my answer being off, feel free to downvote it.