# how to extract multiple records by comparing unique id in mySQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql, excel, phpmyadmin

how to extract multiple records by comparing unique id in mySQL.

I have one excel file.

Which is having 36k records with unique id on every record.

Unique Id is random number start from 11493 (Minimum) to 258090 (Maximum) - reason is, it was extracting at one stage from main table of 700k records.

Main table in MySQL - Phpmyadmin Over 700k records

and i need to compare Unique Id with 700k table unique id and fetch all 36k records only

In excel file and table have one thing common [UNIQUE ID]

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 3):

You can load data into a temporary table and join that with your real table to get the records you want. This is what you will have to do

1) Create a temporary table.  Add relevant indexes to speed up your query.

```
create temporary table record_ids (int id);
```

2) Load the data from your excel file (export to CSV) into the temporary table

```
LOAD DATA INFILE "<path to your file>"
INTO TABLE record_ids
COLUMNS TERMINATED BY ','
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
IGNORE 1 LINES;
```

3) get the records you want by joining with the temporary table.

```
SELECT at.* 
FROM   actual_table at 
       INNER JOIN record_ids ri 
               ON at.id = ri.id = at.id;
```

Answer (score 0):

Simplest way to do this is create one simple query as:

```
select * from TABLENAME where unique_id in (COMMA SEPARATED UNIQUE IDS);
```

Assuming you know how to make them comma separated in excel file.

Thats all

Comment: He's trying to get 36k records. IN clause will not be efficient.

Comment: @ArvindSridharan explain both the queries then: my query will examine 700k records if unique_id is not indexed, if you make index in unique_id then 36k only, Now see your query will examine 700k*36k. Decide which one is efficient?

Comment: IN clause does not use indexes. efficient indexes on the temp table can speed up the query manifold. see http://stackoverflow.com/a/6219545/728610

Comment: @ArvindSridharan my bad, true...

Comment: I thought the same when you posted the comment but digging through mysql docs and SO helped.