# Does it make sense to index a string field in a table with few rows

Tags: mysql, sql

```
create table foo (id, name varchar(255), value varchar(255));
```

Does it make sense to index `name` field in `foo` table which consists `25` rows only, where most of the queries are like `select * from foo where name = 'name1';` and none of these things change much.

Comment: Don't add index in this case, mysql probably will do a full scan any way, even if it uses index, it might just be unwanted overhead.

Comment: Related question: [No indexes on small tables?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/252865/no-indexes-on-small-tables)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If it contains only 25 rows, then it might be overhead instead of performance gain. and query optimizer might opt to not use this index.

Answer (score 6):

Don't add index in this case, mysql probably will do a full scan any way, even if it uses index, it might just be unwanted overhead.

Answer (score 1):

Is `name` unique?

If it is, you need a unique index to maintain data integrity.

If not, when you expand the query to do JOINs etc then the lack of index may hurt. For 25 static rows, how can it add overhead?

I disagree with other answers...