# Optimum number of rows in a table for creating indexes

Tags: sql-server, indexing

My understanding is that creating indexes on small tables could be more cost than benefit.

For example, there is no point creating indexes on a table with less than 100 rows (or even 1000 rows?)

Is there any specific number of rows as a threshold for creating indexes?

**Update 1**

The more I am investigating, the more I get conflicting information. I might be too concern about preserving IO write operations; since my SQL servers database is in HA Synchronous-commit mode.

Point #1:

This question concerns very much the IO write performance. With scenarios like SQL Server HA Synchronous-commit mode, the cost of IO write is high when database servers reside in cross subnet data centers. Adding indexes adds to the expensive IO write cost.

Point #2:

[Books Online](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj835095(v=sql.110).aspx) suggests:

> Indexing small tables may not be optimal because it can take the query
>   optimizer longer to traverse the index searching for data than to
>   perform a simple table scan. Therefore, indexes on small tables might
>   never be used, but must still be maintained as data in the table
>   changes.

I am not sure adding index to a table with only 1 one row will ever have any benefit - or am I wrong?

Comment: Why do you feel that? Having an `id` column is a great way to be able to join two tables even if the tables are small. It's a unique identifier.

Comment: Don't guess, use the Query Analyzer to see whether a specific *query* will benefit from indexes. Although, a clustered index at least, makes any table access faster because it orders rows on disk.

Comment: There is a suggested minimum number of rows where an index can help your system. That answer is 1.

Comment: Again all depend on what use are you going to give to that table. And as always you need to test it

Answer (score 4):

Your understanding is wrong. Small tables also benefit from index specially when are used to join with bigger tables.

The cost of index has two part, storage space and process time during insert/update. First one is very cheap this days so is almost discard. So you only consideration should be when you have a table with lot of updates and inserts apply the proper configurations.

Comment: Thanks for help. I though when a table fits in one page, indexes won't benefit much. I guess I was wrong. Does this mean an index could help with a table with only one row (or even 10 rows) ? If yes, then I am puzzled!.

Comment: Continued... Would you be able to refer me to an article that improves my understanding of the benefits of indexes on small tables? I like to learn it in depth. I appreciate your help.

Comment: Here was a similar question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/252865/no-indexes-on-small-tables, consider not all the cases are the same, so testing is always a basic practice. And another article https://richardfoote.wordpress.com/2009/04/16/indexes-on-small-tables-part-i-one-of-the-few/